# Visual Studio Team Services and Karma

Tags: visual-studio, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, azure-pipelines

Any idea how you can run Karma unit tests inside VSTS? Do they have to be integrated with the Visual Studio Test Runner or is there a better way?

The project is purely client-side static SPA website so it has no Visual Studio solution or project.

Also It seems like even when I try to run Karma via NPM it seems like PhantomJS refuses to start on the Agent.

Logs from the Build:

```
2016-08-03T02:45:44.9647601Z webpack: bundle is now VALID.
2016-08-03T02:45:44.9717626Z [32m03 08 2016 02:45:44.968:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
2016-08-03T02:45:44.9767811Z [32m03 08 2016 02:45:44.976:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
2016-08-03T02:46:44.9784272Z [33m03 08 2016 02:46:44.977:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
2016-08-03T02:46:46.9783856Z [33m03 08 2016 02:46:46.977:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
2016-08-03T02:46:48.9792421Z [33m03 08 2016 02:46:48.978:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1602394Z npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1722407Z ##[debug]rc:1
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1722407Z ##[debug]success:false
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1722407Z ##[debug]taskRunner fail
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1732408Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1782402Z ##[error]Npm failed with error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 1
2016-08-03T02:46:49.1962405Z Finishing task: Npm
2016-08-03T02:46:49.2032405Z ##[error]System.Exception: Task Npm failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
2016-08-03T02:46:49.2042402Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your configuration of steps, but it's works perfectly fine on my build definition.

[image]

Check also capabilities of your agent, should have node.js and npm capability.